# Why is the right hand side zero when we solve a non-linear equation?

Tags: numerical-methods, nonlinear-system, newton-raphson

While solving non-linear equations using Newton-Raphson's method we set the right hand side to zero. Why is that? Do you have any ideas?

Comment: Please add additional thoughts of yourself. That is crucial here for knowing other's views. And *fix the typo in title*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The equation $f(x)=0$ is the standard form. The more general form $g(x)=\alpha$ can be reduced to the standard form by the definition $f(x) = g(x) - \alpha$. There are no pressing reasons to prefer one over the other.